# How to send a multipart/form-data request in cypress which having xml file

Tags: javascript, cypress, e2e, nodejs

I'm having a POST request which have multipart/form-data content and data in xml like below
userlist: "

```
    <user id="ttt1@abc.com" password="Password1" path="sysadm/PauseAndResumeTests" givenname="tttFirst1" familyname="tttLast1">
        <resource id="20369" resultmode="create_notstarted"></resource>
    <resource id="20537" resultmode="create_notstarted"></resource>
    </user>
</userlist>"
function: "abc"
authentication: "3Xi6GuQKKyHwCDD9"
```

**Below is code which i'm trying but it's throwing Missing boundary error**

```
 cy.fixture("xml.xml").then((fileContent) => {
        cy.request({
            method: "POST",
            url: "https://localhost:8080", 
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data;
                charset:"utf-8"   
            },
            formData: true,
            body: {
                userlist:fileContent,
                function: "abc",
                authentication: "3Xi6GuQKKyHwCDD9",
            },
        }).then((response) => {
            console.log(response.body);
            expect(response.status).to.eq(200);
```